# How to pass array data between two routes in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to pass an array from one `Vuejs` route to another, say from `home.vue` to `post.vue` .

This is my `route.js` file for `post.vue`

```
{
  path: '/post/:cart',
  name: 'post',
  component: PostView,
  props: true
}
```

This is my `home.vue`

```
<router-link to="/post/:cart">Check out</router-link>
```

and my `post.vue`

```
  props: ['cart'],
  mounted () {
    console.log(this.$route.params.cart)
  }
```

But this is not working, it just prints `:cart` in the console. I want actual data which is stored in cart. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What have you tried? You must show that you have tried to at least do it yourself before you ask for help

Comment: In Vuejs documentation it only says params and props and query, well I had some difficulty in understanding those and even using them, I'm really new to this topic. At some point I came across `this.$route.params.cart`, used this with params but page shows no error but it does not display anything.

Comment: You could use a small state machine to do what you want as well. Would save data in the URL and can scale with your app. Check out Vuex for an example (this might be too much for a small app but you get the idea of what I'm saying from it).

Comment: Thanks webnoob, it worked. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace `<router-link to="/post/:cart">Check out</router-link>` with `<router-link to="/post/test">Check out</router-link>` you will see `test` in the console. This is because using `:cart` you declared a placeholder for the parameter "cart" in the redirect.

If you want to pass more params I think that you can try 
somethink similar to `<router-link :to="{ path: '/post/', params: { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' }}">Check out</router-link>` but probably you need to change your route.js removing `:cart`

Comment: Thanks it helped, but for my case it won't work, and I got the answer i have to declare it in `App.Vue`, and pass it like props. Thanks once again.